# SQL Server date conversion

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

Right now I'm converting my datetime using

```
     CONVERT(CHAR(10), date, 107)
```

which outputs as follow

```
     Mon dd, yyyy
```

Now, I would like to print

```
     Mon yyyy
```

[edit] "Mon" in "Mon yyyy" means "Month"

How do I do this?

Comment: Your code returns `Mar 14, 20` for me. Ah, `Mon` = `Month` not `Monday` - thought that was odd!

Comment: By "Mon" you mean Month (use MMM instead). It could be misread as "Mon"-day!

Comment: This is not a localized question; it's not unusual to want to display `Mar 2011` in a column. Not sure why the votes to close...

Comment: When in doubt, check the [CONVERT documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)...

Comment: @bmanu, you might want to look at the supported formats for Convert [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx).

Comment: @OMG Ponies - 34 seconds faster finding the link. <g>

Comment: @OMG your edit changed the output completely

Comment: @Richard aka cyberkiwi: "Month" means what - name or number?  I fail to see how your edit improved anything.

Comment: @OMG My edit preserved the intent of the output, which is 8 characters "Mon yyyy", although a more advanced user would have stated "mmm yyyy". It is clear from CONVERT specifier `107` that the desired output is Month abbreviation not number.

Comment: sorry for the confusion with the Mon, but it actually comes from the MSDN doc http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx

Comment: Well played! Programming experience outside SQL Server leads to too many assumptions.. "Mon yyyy" it is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly CHAR(10) is not large enough to hold `MMM DD, YYYY` (12 char).

Secondly, this is a generic way to remove characters from the middle of some output, using the [STUFF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188043.aspx) function.

```
stuff(CONVERT(CHAR(12), [date], 107), 4,4, '')
```

This chops off 4 characters, starting from the 4th, replacing it with nothing.

```
MMM DD, YYYY
123456789012
   XXXX           << removed
```

Comment: FYI: [STUFF is SQL Server 2005+ - see documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188043.aspx)

Comment: @OMG `FYI: STUFF is SQL Server 2005+` Is that your joke for today? It predates SQL Server and was carried from Sybase

Comment: Sybase functionality matters to a question tagged "sql-server"?  You're the joke, putting your foot in your mouth

Comment: @OMG `Sybase functionality matters to a question tagged "sql-server"? You're the joke, putting your foot in your mouth` if you want to dig holes, go ahead. The new style books online combines 2005+ with a dropdown. That is the *ONLY* reason you don't see 2000/7.0/6.5 in there.  If you didn't know, SQL Server was based off Sybase, and so it *inherited* the function `STUFF`. Are we clear?

Comment: SQL Server hasn't shared Sybase code since the first version.  Post a link to documentation, because you have nothing material to substantiate with.  Edit: You won't search because you know it doesn't exist.

Comment: @OMG - [This KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/276195) shows `STUFF` was around at least as far back as 7.0

Comment: @OMG Ponies: Let's paraphrase: "STUFF" has been there forever in SQL Server. I used on 6.5 in the last millennium

Answer (score 0):

1) Why? this is a presentation issue -- it doesn't belong in the database.

2) Easy:

```
DECLARE @foo DATETIME
SET @foo = '20110101'
SELECT @foo
SELECT RIGHT(CONVERT(CHAR(11), @foo, 106), 8)
```

Results

```
Jan 2011
```